# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y^2+f(y)) = f(x-y^2-f(y))$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, substitution

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y^2+f(y)) = f(x-y^2-f(y))$.

There is actually a proof that $f\equiv c$ and $f(x) = -x^2$ are the only ones - it goes through the not too natural substitution $g(x) = f(x) + x^2$ and using that in the resulting equation every real number can be written as a difference of the form $g(y) - g(z)$.

I am looking for a different and a bit more natural approach, e.g. that $f$ must be periodic (if it is different from the abovementioned solutions). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps $f$ is in some kind of specific function space?

Comment: @Novo no idea if this would help since at the end we have to reach essentially two possibilities for $f$ (and not a whole abstract-ish space)

Comment: I wouldn't call the substitution $g(x)=f(x)+x^2$ "not too natural". The part of the equation that depends on the independent variable $y$ is appearing only in the form of $g(y)$. Also, the dependence of $g$ on $f$ is such that one can simply rewrite the functional equation in terms of $g$, which takes the form
$$g\bigl(x+g(y)\bigr)=g\bigl(x-g(y)\bigr)+4xg(y)\text,$$
or by substituting $x+g(y)$ for $x$,
$$g\bigl(x+2g(y)\bigr)=g(x)+4\bigl(x+g(y)\bigr)g(y)\text,$$
which is, in my humble opinion, an algebraically-nicer-looking equation than the original one.

Comment: I would even say that defining $h(x)=2g(x)$ and solving the equivalent problem of finding $h$ with
$$ h \bigl ( x + h ( y ) \bigr ) = h ( x ) + 2 \bigl ( 2 x + h ( y ) \bigr ) h ( y ) $$
is more "natural" than that (regardless of whether it helps with solving the problem more easily or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ following holds
$$ f(x) = f(x+2y^2+2f(y)) \label{eq:main} $$
If $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq -x^2$, then $f$ is periodic. If $\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ is period of $f$, then for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(x + 2(y+\mathfrak{p})^2 + 2f(y + \mathfrak{p})) \\
&= f(x + 4y\mathfrak{p} + 2\mathfrak{p}^2 + 2y^2 + 2f(y)) \\
&= f(x + 4y\mathfrak{p} + 2\mathfrak{p}^2)
\end{align}
This implies that $f$ is constant.

Any constant function and $f(x) = -x^2$ satisfy the equation, so they are the only solutions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I will assume $f$ is continuous.

Now if $f(y)+y^2$ is nonconstant then the image $I:=\{f(y)+y^2:y\in\mathbb R\}$ contains some open interval $(a,b)$. Now for any $z\in (a,b)\subseteq I$ and any $x\in\mathbb R$ we have that $f(x-z)=f(x+z)$, by our assumption. Thus, $f$ has period $2z$. Now, every real number in $(2a,2b)$ is a period of $f$, which shows that $f$ must be constant.